# Need Help to create a Bash Script for Mac OSX 12.6+ with a menu to select another Bash Script file

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm on Mac OSX 12.6+ and will be on 13.0+.  I need to create a Bash Script with a menu or options to select 1 of 4 scripts but never multiple scripts...  I have found some for Linux boxes, python but not for Mac OSX Terminal window

here is an example of what I found for Linux boxes

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Select your Script please: "

select scpt in Script1 Script2 Script3 Quit
do
    case $scpt in
        "Script1")
            echo "$scpt - This is Script1" | /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Script1.sh;;
        "Script2")
           echo "$scpt - This is Script2" | /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Script2.sh;;
        "Script3")
           echo "$scpt - This is Script3" | /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Script3.sh;;
        "Quit")
           echo "We're done"
           break;;
        *)
           echo "Ooops";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Not sure I get the point of any question, is any there ?

Comment: This will work on the mac. Have you tried it?

Comment: If you have bash, there's nothing specific to mac

Comment: Show us exactly why you think your current code is wrong/broken. If there's an error message, or an undesired symptom, that should be part of the question itself.

Comment: (btw, do you really want those `echo`s to go to the input of your other script? That stops those other scripts from reading from the user, and also means that the `echo` output _isn't_ going to the terminal)

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue... here is what I came up with

```
#!/bin/zsh



PS3="Select your Script please: "



select scpt in "Wipe and Reset Setting" "Back up Users Data" "Transfer Users Data from old Mac to new Mac" "Update Mac OSX to 12.6.2" Quit

do

    case $scpt in

        "Wipe and Reset Setting")

            echo "$scpt - This is Script1" | zsh /Volumes/Ventoy/Scripts/MAC_Scripts/MAC-Data_and_Profiles-WIPE.zsh
            break;;


        "Back up Users Data")

           echo "$scpt - This is Script2" | zsh /Volumes/Ventoy/Scripts/MAC_Scripts/MAC-Copy-Data-to-Home-Drive.zsh
           break;;


        "Transfer Users Data from old Mac to new Mac")

           echo "$scpt - This is Script3" | zsh /Volumes/Ventoy/Scripts/MAC_Scripts/MAC-Data-Transfer_RUN_from_New_Mac.zsh
           break;;


        "Update Mac OSX to 12.6.2")

           echo "$scpt - This is Script3" | zsh /Volumes/Ventoy/Scripts/MAC_Scripts/MAC-OS-update-12.6.2-Local.sh Local.zsh
           break;;
           

        "Quit")

           echo "Closing this script"

           break;;

       else)

        echo "Ooops";;

    esac

done
```

Comment: `bash` or POSIX `sh` should also work. Why switch to `zsh`?

Comment: Resolve what issue? Changing shells? So all of the other scripts you are invoking with `zsh` should also support that.